# SharePoint2013 referencing external JS file in page layout not working

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have created a custom page layout. In that custom page layout I have many HTML markup and controls like Dropdowns, hyperlinks (hrefs) etc.  Clicking on hyperlink hides or shows a div. The HTML markup and controls shows up fine when I create a page from page layout.
The issue I am having is the JavaScript to hide or show div is in external JS file, which I am referencing in the page layout as below:-

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink name="~sitecollection/Style Library/Scripts/my.js" runat="server" />
```

But when I click on “hyperlinks (hrefs)” the script in external js file doesn’t fire.
I also tried using

```
<script src="../../mysite/Style%20Library/Scripts/my.js"></script>
```

Any idea what’s wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with following links:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://SharePoint/sites/SiteName/_catalogs/masterpage/Master%20Page%20Template/test.js"></script>

<SharePoint:ScriptLink id="ScriptExternalJs" runat="server"  Name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/MyCustomStyles/js/TestScript.js" OnDemand="false" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" ></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
```

Comment: I tried with "Script" tag and "ScriptLink" as you suggested but none of them work. I placed those in "PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" content area.

Comment: Are you getting any error in your console window?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the js file in script tag and Place it just above the Publishing:EditModePanel tag

```
<!--MS:<Publishing:EditModePanel runat="server" id="editmodestyles">-->
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a module in sharepoint like "scripts".

Add ur js file under the module and then refer the file in layout.

Comment: Create a module in sharepoint like "scripts".

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Scripts">
    <File Path="Scripts\jquery-1.8.2.min.js" Url="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" />
    <File Path="Scripts\JSCSOM.js" Url="Scripts/JSCSOM.js" />
  </Module>
</Elements>

Add ur js file under the module and then refer the file in layout.

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/JSCSOM.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

Answer (score -2):

You need to add

```
    //<!{CDATA[//]]>
```

after each of your script links. i.e.

```
    <script type = "text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/Style%20Library/myjsfile.js">//<!{CDATA[//]]>
```

Make sure you put your script link into the 'PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead' block towards the top of the html page layout - just after the close of the edit mode panel is a good spot.